# Spring: Passing List of Object from Ajax to RestController

Tags: ajax, json, spring

I am having the problem. I tried many ways but it didn't solve

My problem is passing object list from ajax to restcontroller
My Ajax seem be:

```
var answers = [{"question_id":"John", "answer":"Doe"},{"question_id":"Anna", "answer":"Smith"}];
        $("#btn-submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "check",
                dataType : 'json',
                data: answers,
                success : function() {
                    console.log("ok");
                },
                error : function(errors_dict) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

My Spring Server I tried ArrayList or Answers: Class List of Answer.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/check", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String answer(Answers answers) {
...
}
```

But answers.size() is alway 0

Comment: I'm not a guru but a few things come to mind. Can you convert `JSON` to `String` automatically. I usually transform JSON into `HashMap`. Also, does it change anything if you add ` consumes = "application/json"` to the `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: @bitoiu Thanks for your help! I found add @ RequestBody to @ ResponseBody to fix my problem!
I don't know why I had error when I added it before :(